# "JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array" (twitter4j, twitterapi, JSONObject)

Tags: java, arrays, twitter4j, json

That is my first question here and for me. Please be advised: I searched this whole forum and I really got the feeling, I have overseen something! So I just ask for my "special" case.

I have a `.json` file, which is correct and starts with array (validated through jsonlint.com).

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, JSONException {
    String inputPath = "/home/e/Desktop/";

    FileReader br = new FileReader(inputPath + "Antikoerperyosi.json");

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(br);


    try {
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length(); ++index) {
            JSONObject hashTag = array.getJSONObject(index);
            System.out.println(hashTag);
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I managed to read out a single `.json` and after correcting my files json syntax, I got really confused of how to tell to grab from the object "status" the object "entities" and then from object "entities" the array "hashtags".

I will append the first two lines of my JSON in hope it will make it easier to understand my point. (I could not attend, I a am new here)

JSON-File(snippet, I cannot intend if I am not mistaken..):
"status":{....."entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[{"indices":[35,44],"text":"LuxLeaks"},{"indices":[49,62],"text":"Handelsblatt"}],
next JSON[..."status":{.....}], etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you show the json file please?

Comment: It is good idea to add a tag of language, it looks it is http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info You could fix the listing too: delete dead or unimportant code, fix indentions.

Comment: I formatted your code with just indentation, and it looks like there's an extra bracket at the end if I'm not mistaken? Was this a typo on your part, or is your code throwing an error?

Comment: Sorry, typo! I kicked the "public class" statement!